# Free tool to share one windows application to android (no control)

Tags: windows-10, android

this is my first question here although I've also found a lot of answers here before, but excuse any errors I make (feel free to edit out the rambling as well if you want). Also, if this is a duplicate of any question, that I haven't found, feel free to direct me there. Additionally, please suggest any missing and fitting tags that I haven't found.

Anyway, I've looked through previous questions and several google searches and I haven't found a tool that fulfills the following conditions:

- free to use
- no timeout (like TeamViewer)
- available for Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- Android client (so I can see it on my phone)
- share only a single App (the goal is to keep track of an app that runs in the background while I have other fullscreen apps)
- anonymous use possible (even Skype uses phone number / email + full name nowadays)

Features I don't need:

- control
- high resolution
- fast response time
- fluid image (I'm fine with a compressed low res image every 5 seconds or even less)
- multiple clients
- connection via Server (p2p is preferred, actually)

All the professional tools I've found do a lot more than I need, so I figured there should be a simpler one available with reduced features, but I haven't found any.

Not having this is more of an inconvenience rather than a huge problem so I actually have the time to wait for an answer here, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) or something similar (game streaming softwares) to stream only a single window. You can probably stream this to Twitch/Youtube under an obscure name or look for a streaming website that allows password protection.

On Android, just install the streaming client.